# Can the pointer returned by sys _brk overlap the stack on Linux?

Tags: linux, sbrk, brk

Based on info in https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/brk.2.html, the *brk* Linux system call works like this:

- `void *sys_brk(void *desired_break) { return (void*)syscall(SYS_brk, desired_break); }`
- It changes the virtual memory mapping of the current process, by growing or shrinking the read-write data region. The *break* is the end of the data region. To get the beginning of the data region (beyond sections containing global variables such as `.data` and `.bss`), call `sys_brk(NULL)` near the beginning of the program.
- It always returns the new break (both success and failure), which may be different from *desired_break*, especially on failure, because then the break is unchanged.

Quoting a comment in *musl-1.1.16/src/malloc/expand_heap.c* :

> defend against buggy brk implementations that can cross the stack.

My question: **Does the brk system call in Linux ever create the data region which can overlap with the stack of the main thread?**

More specifically, was there an overlap in early Linux versions? If there was, when was it fixed?

I'm not interested in kernel bugs which happen only with address randomization. I'm not interested in kernel bugs which happen only when a dynamic loader (e.g. */lib/ld-linux.so.2*) is used.

I'm asking this because I'm writing a minimalistic *malloc* implementation, which uses *sys_brk* under the hood, for Linux only, and I'd like to keep it as short as possible. (Please note that in this question I'm not interested in *malloc* implementations not using *sys_brk*.) If in Linux there is no overlap between the data region and the stack, then I don't have to check for that in my *malloc* implementation, thus it becomes shorter.

Comment: my first google hit for "buggy brk linux" https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1749633

Comment: @KamilCuk: More details here about thus bug: https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/ChangeLog-4.19.75 . It looks like an obscure rare bug which doesn't affect me. I've updated the question.